# No se me cargan los estilos al iniciar un servidor en flask

Tags: html, python, css, python-3.x, flask

No se me cargan los estilos css de mi pagina cuando la inicio a través de flask, pero si abro el archivo por su cuenta si los carga.

Este es mi código de flask:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/microfonos_para_cantar')
def microfonos_para_cantar():
    return render_template('microfonosCanto.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Adjunta todo tu codigo para reproducir el error, o si lo tienes en git, así es muy difícil ayudarte. Puede simplemente la ruta de tu archivo esta mal, recuerda que se cargan diferentes.

Comment: Debes meter los estilos del html a la carpeta static, aqui mas informacion. http://lineadecodigo.com/python/usar-estaticos-aplicacion-flask/

Answer (score 0):

Lo que deberías hacer es que en el atributo `href` de tu etiqueta `link` uses `url_for`, por ejemplo:

```
<link href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/mi_estilo.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Lo que estoy queriendo decir con esto es que mis estilos están en:
/static/styles/mi_estilo.css